# Can't find HDD in SSD+HDD setup?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, ssd

I recently got a new computer that has a 240 GB SSD and a 2 TB HDD. I'm working with Windows 10 installed on the SSD, but I can't find the HDD on my computer.

When I go to Devices and Drives, I see the C: drive:

[image]

and going into Properties, apparently both disk drives are working properly.

SSD:

[image]

and HDD:

[image]

But still, the total storage:

[image]

is reported to be 223 GB, which I assume is just from the SSD.

Do I have to do something extra to get the HDD recognized?

I really just want to use it to store music and video files, etc.

Comment: start disk management and assign a drive letter to the HDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you format the drive to use a file system that's recognisable by Windows?

You can do this from Computer Management, clicking Storage, right click the drive and select format.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/create-format-hard-disk-partition